# How to compile solidity in the browser without using browser-solc?

Tags: solidity, solc

I am thinking of implementing an API call to compile some source code entered by a user and then return the bytecode for deployment using metamask.

I have tried browser-solc but it had some errors and I want to try and alternative approach.

Did anyone have sample code to compile source on the server using node for example?

Comment: If this is about deploying configured-to-order contracts from templates, you could consider a contract factory pattern. While this doesn't have the flexibility of letting users compile arbitrary source code, it avoids the security concerns around accepting arbitrary bytecode.

Comment: I have a solution which uses an API call to a node program and then it runs solc. It  works but can be slow.